# javascript cross page variables not working

Tags: javascript

i have this javascript script shared between all my web pages:

```js
if(document.location.pathname == '/' || document.location.pathname == '/index.php'){
window.hello='hello';
window.alert(window.hello);
}
else
{
window.alert(window.hello);
}
```

the **window.hello** variable should be (as far as i know) a cross page variable, so it should display 'hello' in every page (having first loaded index.php), but that happens only in the index page, while the others display 'undefined'  .... someone knows why?

Comment: "the window.hello variable should be (as far as i know) a cross page variable" — Entirely untrue. Variables exist only in the current page.

Comment: `a cross page variable` - there is no such thing

Answer (score -1):

`window.hello` is a global variable and is added as a property to the global object.

A new global object is created for each page, hence your problem...

Comment: so what should i use?

Comment: Downvote please explain?

Comment: not on purpose man , sorry i am new in Stackoverflow

Comment: Possible solutions: include the same script in all your pages (if it is a constant), localStorage, sessionStorage, cookie, URL or roundtrip to the server, etc.

Comment: what about sessionStorage?